# Understanding rspec test for uniqueness -- listing 6.18

Tags: rspec, railstutorial.org

I am trying to understand the test for uniqueness constraint in listing 6.18 (rails 3.2).

```
describe "when email address is already taken" do
  ...
  before do
    user_with_same_email = @user.dup
    user_with_same_email.save
  end
  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

"The method here is to make a user with the same email address as @user, which we accomplish using @user.dup, which creates a duplicate user with the same attributes. Since we then save that user, the original @user has an email address **that already exists in the database**, and hence should not be valid."

The part I am not clear on is where/when is the first user saved to database ? i.e. There is no call to user.save. Where be the auto magic ?

Thanks,

KA

Answer (score 0):

The first user is never saved. The test setup initializes (but does not save) a user, then dups it and saves the copy. Then it tries to validate the original (unsaved) user. Because the copy has the same email address, `valid?` returns `false`.

Comment: Right ! understood. Need to pay attention to what `it` is referring to in `it { should_not be_valid }`. Thanks much.